# Selecting a cell value in jQuery, when the table is generated using JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So my table is created (all the cells and headers at least) within javasscript/jquery on document.ready. I want to be able to get the left most cell value, when a button is pressed on the same row. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Please provide the HTML of the table and the JS code that you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to answer to 100% without the actual data, but

```
$(this).parents("tr:first");
```

will return the row that you are currently on.

and chaining it to find the first td child

```
$(this).parents("tr:first").find("td:first");
```

This should all be placed within the handler you are using, but I do not know how you are handling clicks and such or how you are finding your buttons.

to get the final contents of the cell, chain it one step further:

```
$(this).parents("tr:first").find("td:first").text();
```

Comment: This is returning [object Object] because the data was in JSON format but processed in to the table. The JSON ID for that particular cell would just be "id", how would I manage to specify this?

Comment: This is just to return the cell itself, you should be able to use "val()" or more likely "text()" to get the actual contents out.

Comment: I always miss silly little things like that! Perfect, thank you!

Comment: Using .parents() is inefficient, as it returns ALL the parents.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$("tr > button").live('click', function(){
    //do stuff on click
    $(this).();
});
```

As the table is created by jQuery on load, you'll need to use the .live(), or .on() methods as .click() won't work for you.

https://api.jquery.com/live/

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: The .live() event was deprecated quite a few versions ago, so be sure to check your version!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the concept. When a button with the class "myButton" in a row is clicked, it finds the closest parent row, looks for the first table cell in that parent row, and alerts the value (you can do whatever you like with cellContent once the value is assigned). Whether this works for you depends on your HTML, it is good to supply that with questions you ask.

```
$('.myButton').on('click', function() {
   var cellContent;
   cellContent = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').slice(0).val();
   alert(cellContent);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this in your click handler:

```
$(event.target).closest('tr').find('td:first').text()
```